# MYSQL select * from table where owner_id equals one id from array

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently struggling with a logically rather simple task.

I have an array with friend IDs like so : `[12,321,14,2]`

Now I'd like to select all rows from my posts table where the `owner_id` matches at least one entry in the array.

So far I've tried to get it to work with FIND IN SET but I am not sure if it'll lead to an end..

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
select * from `table`
where `owner_id` in (12,321,14,2)
```

Comment: Yes ! I just found that answer somewhere else but thank you, thats exactly waht I needed